# Dapp architecture & ERC1155

Tags: tokens, dapps, erc-1155

There are 2 smart contracts: Contract `Game` and Contract `Token(ERC1155)`. I have 2 implementation options: Make the inheritance `contract Game is Token {}` and work with the token directly or `Game` separately, `Token` separately (interact via the `IToken token interface`). Which option is better to use?